# How can I delete some pages from a pdf document using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, file, pdf, itext

I am overwriting pages in a pdf file based on a user-specified sequence. I'm trying to set my code up in a way that selects the pages I want to keep from a file, store those pages as objects in memory, overwrite that same file completely, then write those pages back to the file, then append as needed by the user.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
    reader.SelectPages("1-5"));
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new 
    FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

The issue I'm running into is that the PdfStamper can't initialize because the file it wants to use for writing is already open for the PdfReader. How can I read the pages from the PdfReader into memory so that I can close it, then write to the same file after purging it?

Comment: Why not a different file-name?

Comment: It's for scanning software so if there's a jam or something on page 4, then I need to preserve all the files until that one, delete page 4, and then append newly scanned pages as they come in.

Comment: How about reading the original file into memory (byte array) and initializing the pdf reader from that array? This way the file is not locked. Obviously, though, if something happens during writing, you don't have any copy if the file anymore...

Answer (score 0):

To 'delete' pages just need to select pages You want to keep like:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("Pdf_FilePath.pdf")
pdfReader.selectPages("1-3,5-10"); //Now You have pages without page no.4
```

Write changes to pdf using:

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                        new FileOutputStream("Result_Pdf_FilePath.pdf"));
```

And close Stamper and Reader

```
pdfStamper.close();
```

If you want to Save the file in the same path, you can use tempfile, and then after closing Reader copy temp file and overwrite old one, and delete temp file.

Comment: Can you expand on how to save the old pages to a temp file?

Comment: Can be made exactly the same way as removing pages, but remove opposite pages

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it worked very well. Try this:

Notes: The original PDF has 4 pages and I removed page.
I used the library: "iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core"

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fullName = "C:\\tmp\\pm\\Contract\\_models\\Proposta Saude.pdf";
        PDFTest(fullName);

        Console.WriteLine("Finish!!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static private void PDFTest(string fileName)
    {
        using (Stream resultPDFOutputStream = new FileStream(path: "C:\\tmp\\pm\\Contract\\_models\\Proposta Saude -2.pdf", mode: FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Create a reader from the file bytes.
            var reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            reader.SelectPages("1-2,4");

            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, resultPDFOutputStream);
            pdfStamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question, the op in particular wanted to save to the same file he read from.